# Lodash _.merge function not overwriting properties with updated information

Tags: node.js, mongoose, lodash, put

In my user edit route, I am trying to use the Lodash merge function to update the returned user document (from Mongoose) with the updates sent in req.body. Here is my code:

```
    const { dobYear, dobMonth, dobDay } = req.body;
    const dob = formatDob(dobYear, dobMonth, dobDay);

    const user = await db.User.findById(req.params.id); 

    const updates = pick(req.body, [ 'fullName', 'email', 'password', 'gender', 'address', 'avatar_url' ]);
    merge(user, [updates, dob]);
    let updatedUser = await user.save();
```

The problem is even when I send an updated email in the request, the merge does not seem to actually overwrite the old email value with the new one (from `updates`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to merge an object with an array in the way you are passing the arguments to `merge`.

[See documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge). And I assume your confusion came from the fact that in the docs they have `_.merge(object, [sources])`. However if you see in the `Arguments` section they have:

`[sources] (...Object): The source objects.` Meaning a list of objects rather than an actual array.

Try this:

```js
var user = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 };     
var updates = { 'a': 3, 'c': 4, 'email': 'aaa@bbb.com' };
let dob = '11-11-2019'

let result = _.merge(user, updates, {dob});  // <-- ...Object

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

merge(user, [updates, dob]);.

Incorrect usage. Accepts the following :

```
Arguments

    object (Object): The destination object.
    [sources] (...Object): The source objects.
```

Observe the..., that means it accepts a variable number of arguments.

`merge(user, updates, { dob })`